# join tables on different amount of columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I wanna replace values in the column **Attribute** in T1 with the values from T2. If sub_id is NULL in T2, then replace **f** values in T1 with **t** for all the rows with ID in T2, otherwise do it only for the rows with sub_id.

Below are the dummy tables and the result I get.

```
    WITH T1 AS (  SELECT 1 AS id, 2 as sub_id, '2017-08-20' AS date, 'f' AS attribute UNION ALL
          SELECT 1, 3 as sub_id, '2017-08-19', 'f' UNION ALL
          SELECT 1, 4 as sub_id,'2017-08-18', 'f' UNION ALL
          SELECT 2, 5 as sub_id,'2017-08-20', 'f' UNION ALL
          SELECT 2, 6 as sub_id,'2017-08-19', 'f' 
        ),
        T2 AS (
          SELECT 1 AS id, null as sub_id, '2017-08-19' AS date, '2017-08-25' AS date_end, 't' AS attribute UNION ALL
          SELECT 2, 5 as sub_id,'2017-08-19', '2017-08-25' AS date_end, 't' UNION ALL
          SELECT 2, 6 as sub_id,'2017-08-19', '2017-08-25' AS date_end, 't'
        )
        SELECT
          a.id,
          a.date,
          a.sub_id,
          COALESCE(b.attribute, a.attribute) as attribute
        FROM T1 AS a
        LEFT JOIN T2 AS b
        ON a.id = b.id AND a.date >= b.date AND a.date <= b.date_end 
    AND a.sub_id = case when b.sub_id is not null then a.sub_id end
```

In the above result I wanna have the attribute column with **t** values in all the eligible rows. 
I achieved what I want with another subquery:

```
WITH T1 AS (  SELECT 1 AS id, 2 as sub_id, '2017-08-20' AS date, 'f' AS attribute UNION ALL
      SELECT 1, 3 as sub_id, '2017-08-19', 'f' UNION ALL
      SELECT 1, 4 as sub_id,'2017-08-18', 'f' UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, 5 as sub_id,'2017-08-20', 'f' UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, 6 as sub_id,'2017-08-19', 'f' 
    ),
    T2 AS (
      SELECT 1 AS id, null as sub_id, '2017-08-19' AS date, '2017-08-25' AS date_end, 't' AS attribute UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, 5 as sub_id,'2017-08-19', '2017-08-25' AS date_end, 't' UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, 6 as sub_id,'2017-08-19', '2017-08-25' AS date_end, 't'
    ) , 
   adv_level AS ( SELECT
      a.id,
      a.date,
      a.sub_id,
      COALESCE(b.attribute, a.attribute) as attribute
    FROM T1 AS a
    LEFT JOIN T2 AS b
    ON a.id = b.id AND a.date >= b.date AND a.date <= b.date_end AND a.sub_id = case when b.sub_id is not null then a.sub_id end)

SELECT
      a.id,
      a.date,
      a.sub_id,
      COALESCE(b.attribute, a.attribute) as attribute
    FROM adv_level AS a
    LEFT JOIN T2 AS b
    ON a.id = b.id AND a.date >= b.date AND a.date <= b.date_end
```

but is there a way to do it just once?

Comment: 1. The last line should probably be switched to `AND (a.sub_id = b.sub_id or b.sub_id IS NULL)` instead of that case. 2. You will never get the third record of `t2` to bring in `t` as it falls outside of the date range in the first record of `t2`.

Comment: worked indeed :)

Comment: Can one of you submit this as an answer to the question?